# Can i distribute an executable with MSVCR100.dll

Tags: python, windows, dll, msvcr100.dll

I use python to create my executable on windows.
My executable depends on MSVCR100.dll.
I want to give clients both the executable and the MSVCR100.dll.
Do I need special permissions to distribute my exe with the dll or is it fine to distribute the exe with the dll without special permissions.

Comment: [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20171104024946/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx
Wayback link for @IInspectable 's URL. The URL is broken right now.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the wrong question, as you need to check if you are allowed to redistribute the Microsoft C++ Runtime Library (MSVCT100.dll is part of it).

Yes, you can. But read [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104024946/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx) for details.